# Esconder um botão ate que 2 input estejam preenchidos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pretendo esconder cada um dos 3 botões ate que os 2 inputs que estão em cima de cada botão estejam preenchidos , eu já tinha tentado fazer e funciona , mas se tento adicionar mais do que uma vez ele fica sempre visivel mesmo com nada nos input

```
    <div id="addElements">
      <input type="text" name="exame" id="examedisciplina"  placeholder="Nome da disciplina">
      <input type="date" id="dataExame" >

      <button type="button" id="add_exame" onclick="addToTableExame()" >Adicionar Exame</button>

       <input type="text" name="teste" id="testedisciplina"  placeholder="Nome da disciplinas">
        <label id='label5'>Data:</label> <input type="date" id="dataTeste" >

       <button type="button" id="add_teste" onclick="addToTableTeste()">Adicionar Teste</button>

       <input type="text" name="trabalho" id="trabalhodisciplina"  placeholder="Nome da disciplinas"><p></p>
        <label id='label6'>Data:</label> <input type="date" id="dataTrabalho" >


      <button type="button" id="add_trabalho" onclick="addToTableTrabalho()">Adicionar Trabalho</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode aplicar um keyup no input e ir verificando o value deles por exemplo:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.form input', function(){
     var val1 = $('.input1').val();
     var val2 = $('.input2').val();
     if(val1 != "" && val2 != ""){
         $('.botao').show();
     }else{
         $('.botao').hide();
     }
});
```

Ou você pode manter o botão visível e no momento em que o usuário o pressionar você verifica se os campos estão vazios e se estiverem você mostra alguma mensagem, como:

```
$('.meuButton').click(function(){
    $(".seuForm input").each(function() {
       if($(this).val() === ""){
          alert("Campos em branco");
       }else{
           //execute sua função aqui
       }
    });
});
```

Ou

```
$('.meuButton').click(function(){
    var val1 = $('.meuInput1').val();
    var val2 = $('.meuInput2').val();
    if(val1 != "" && val2 != ""){
        //execute sua função aqui
    }else{
        alert("Campos em branco");
    }
});
```

Não testei o segundo método mas deve funcionar. 
Obs: Se essa é uma função que vai ficar se repetindo a cada linha que você adicionar, você deve resetar os valores aplicados ao botão em sua função.

Comment: O que o AP precisa é mostrar/esconder se cada 2 inputs estiverem preenchidos. No teu primeiro exemplo só verificas um input.

Comment: A minha ideia era mesmo esconder o botão e só aparecer quando os 2 inputs estiverem preenchidos

Comment: @ForçaChape alterei o exemplo 1 de forma que você possa verificaros inputs, e ainda usar o botão escondido e se mostrar caso os dois campos estejam preenchidos aqui um exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/A7UbK/58/

Comment: A questão é que um dos inputs é do tipo data

Comment: @ForçaChape é só alterar o type do input para date, se a data não for preenchida o mesmo será reconhecido como um campo vázio e o botão não será mostrado http://jsfiddle.net/A7UbK/59/

Comment: o botão fica visivel quando escrevo em apenas 1

Comment: Tem certeza? pois aqui pelo ao menos no fiddle ele só fica visível quando os dois campos estão preenchidos, e quando limpo um campo o botão some

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
(function(bts) {
    bts.each(function() {
        var inputs = $(this).closest('section').find('input');
        inputs.on('change', verificarInputs.bind(this, inputs.get()));
    });
    function verificarInputs(inputs) {
        var preenchidos = inputs.filter(i => !i.value).length == 0;
        $(this).toggle(preenchidos);
    }
})($('#addElements button'));
```

```css
#addElements button {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addElements">
    <section>
        <input type="text" name="exame" id="examedisciplina" placeholder="Nome da disciplina">
        <input type="date" id="dataExame">
        <button type="button" id="add_exame" onclick="addToTableExame()">Adicionar Exame</button>
    </section>
    <section>
        <input type="text" name="teste" id="testedisciplina" placeholder="Nome da disciplinas">
        <label id='label5'>Data:</label>
        <input type="date" id="dataTeste">
        <button type="button" id="add_teste" onclick="addToTableTeste()">Adicionar Teste</button>
    </section>
    <section>
        <input type="text" name="trabalho" id="trabalhodisciplina" placeholder="Nome da disciplinas">
        <label id='label6'>Data:</label>
        <input type="date" id="dataTrabalho">
        <button type="button" id="add_trabalho" onclick="addToTableTrabalho()">Adicionar Trabalho</button>
    </section>
</div>
```

Organizei o HTML um pouco. A ideia no JavaScript / jQuery é correr uma função cada vez que o input muda e gerar um boleano para saber se está tudo preenchido:

```
var preenchidos = inputs.filter(i => !i.value).length == 0;
```

depois mostrar ou esconder o `button` conforme o valor de `preenchidos` com

```
$(this).toggle(preenchidos);
```

Se quiseres manter o mesmo HTML podes fazer assim:

([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zavsLz1m/))

```
(function(bts) {
    bts.each(function() {
        var inputs = $(this).prevAll('input').slice(0, 2);
        inputs.on('change', verificarInputs.bind(this, inputs.get()));
    });

    function verificarInputs(inputs) {
        var preenchidos = inputs.filter(i => !i.value).length == 0;
        $(this).toggle(preenchidos);
    }
})($('#addElements button'));
```

Comment: Não é possivel fazer isso sem mudar  o html ?

Comment: @ForçaChape sim, é possivel. Adicionei à resposta. Ficaria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/zavsLz1m/

Comment: Não sei porque mas no meu os botões não aparecem mesmo que tenha tudo escrito , e copiei examete o codigo do JSFIDDLE

Comment: @ForçaChape onde estás a colocar o JavasScript? Coloca no final da página...

Comment: Dentro da função que ocorre quando se carrega no botão mas agora percebi que isso nao faz sentido , onde devo colocar ?

Comment: @ForçaChape coloca como eu tenho na resposta, no final do HTML dentro de tags `<script></script>`